# Возможна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Я: Только не говори, что ты не видел.
>   Костя (,) в замешательстве: Нет, я думал, что все нормально.

Возможна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Если текст диалога оформлен как реплики в пьесах, то:

*Костя (в замешательстве): Нет, я думал, что все нормально.*

> [Ремарки в тексте](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=162), относящиеся к данному лицу, если после ремарки
> следует новая фраза того же лица или если ремаркой заканчивается
> реплика, пишут с прописной буквы, выделяют иным шрифтом и заключают в
> скобки, с точкой внутри скобки:
>
> а) Епиходов. Я пойду. (Натыкается на стул, который падает.) Вот… (Как
> бы торжествуя.) Вот видите, извините за выражение, какое
> обстоятельство, между прочим… (Ч.)
>
> б) Анфиса (увидав Лыняева). Ах, вы уж… уж сами. (Идёт в сад.) (Остр.)
>
> Если же ремарка находится в середине фразы действующего лица, она
> пишется со строчной буквы, выделяется иным шрифтом и заключается в
> скобки, без точки:
>
> Никита. А теперь я пойду (оглядывается кругом) налево.

По ссылке можно посмотреть шрифтовые выделения, но они касаются именно пьес. В обычном воспроизведении диалога возможна как бы "игра под пьесу", без строгостей воспроизведения.